# C++: My if/else doesn't work? No error?

Tags: c++, if-statement

My program is supposed to reject any input more than 1000. I do not get any errors in my code and MS Visual Studio and it lets me compile it, but when I put in 2000, it says "input successful" instead of "please try again".

I am aware that I haven't put the loop in yet, so the "please try again" will not work. However, as of now, I just want the output to say "please try again" and go on to nickels.

```
//  This program prompts the number of coins, and outputs how many cents you have

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    // declaring variables:
    unsigned QUARTERS;
    unsigned DIMES;
    unsigned NICKELS;
    unsigned PENNIES;
    double total;

    cout << "********************************************************" << endl;
    cout << "             Welcome to Crazy Coin Counter!             " << endl;
    cout << "********************************************************" << endl << endl;

    // user input:
    cout << "# QUARTERS: ";
    cin >> QUARTERS;
        if (QUARTERS < 1000)
        cout << "               --> Input Successful!" << endl;
        else if (QUARTERS >= 1000)
        cout << "You cannot put in more than 1000 quarters! Please try again." << endl;
    cout << endl << "# DIMES: ";
    cin >> DIMES;
        if (DIMES < 1000)
        cout << "               --> Input Successful!" << endl;
        else if (DIMES>= 1000)
        cout << "You cannot put in more than 1000 dimes! Please try again." << endl;
    cout << endl << "# NICKLES: ";
    cin >> NICKELS;
        if (NICKELS< 1000)
        cout << "               --> Input Successful!" << endl;
        else if (NICKELS>= 1000)
        cout << "You cannot put in more than 1000 dimes! Please try again." << endl;
    cout << endl << "# PENNIES: ";
    cin >> PENNIES;
        if (PENNIES < 1000)
        cout << "               --> Input Successful!" << endl;
        else if (PENNIES >= 1000)
        cout << "You cannot put in more than 1000 dimes! Please try again." << endl;

    // calculations:

    total = (QUARTERS * 0.25) + (DIMES * 0.1) + (NICKELS * 0.05) + (PENNIES * 0.01);

    // output:

    cout << endl <<endl<< "Congrats! You have       $" << total << "      worth of coins! " << endl << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing braces (`{}`).

Comment: Use a debugger, and your issue will be resolved a lot faster than posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: @RavelaSmyth Your textbook explains about scope blocks already, didn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You are inputting different variables (e.g., `DIMES`, `NICKLES`, etc.), but always checking the value of `QUARTERS`. Just fix each `if` statement to check the variable that was just inputed (using `cin`), and you should be fine.